# unable to run selenium test with firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox

I am have issue running this test and would like help with it. It opens up firefox and closes after i get this error on the page " Accessibility support is partially disabled due to compatibility issues with new Firefox features".

Test

```
package com.example.tests;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class QuestionMark {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\SeleniumGecko\\geckodriver.exe");


    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "https://energy.co.uk";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  }

  @Test
  public void testJava() throws Exception {
    driver.get("https://ondemand.questionmark.com/home/403160/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("edit-name")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("edit-name")).sendKeys("tessy");
    driver.findElement(By.id("edit-pass")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("edit-pass")).sendKeys("xxxxxx");
    driver.findElement(By.id("edit-submit")).click();
    assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='body-container']/div/div/section/div[2]")).getText().matches("^exact:× Error message Sorry, unrecognized username or password\\. Have you forgotten your password[\\s\\S]$"));
    assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Have you forgotten your password?")).getText().matches("^exact:Have you forgotten your password[\\s\\S]$"));
    assertEquals("User", driver.getTitle());
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Request new password")).click();
    assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.linkText("Request new password(active tab)")));
    assertEquals("User", driver.getTitle());
    driver.findElement(By.id("edit-name")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("edit-name")).sendKeys("xxxxx@yahoo.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("edit-submit")).click();
    assertEquals("User", driver.getTitle());
    driver.findElement(By.id("edit-name")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("edit-name")).sendKeys("TechTestUser");
    driver.findElement(By.id("edit-pass")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("edit-pass")).sendKeys("xxxxx");
    driver.findElement(By.id("edit-submit")).click();
    assertEquals("TechTestUser | 403160", driver.getTitle());
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("People")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Users")).click();
    assertEquals("Users", driver.getTitle());
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Import Participants")).click();
    assertEquals("Import Participants | 403160", driver.getTitle());
    driver.findElement(By.id("edit-feeds-feedsfilefetcher-upload")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("edit-feeds-feedsfilefetcher-upload")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Tessy\\Downloads\\Participants.csv");
    driver.findElement(By.id("edit-submit")).click();
    assertEquals("Importing user", driver.getTitle());
    assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.xpath("//div[@id='body-container']/div/div/section/div[2]")));
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }

  private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
      driver.switchTo().alert();
      return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      String alertText = alert.getText();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {
        alert.dismiss();
      }
      return alertText;
    } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Below are the  error on the eclipse log

Jun 03, 2017 1:20:34 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
JavaScript warning: https://ondemand.questionmark.com/home/403160/sites/all/modules/Community/jquery_update/replace/jquery/1.10/jquery.min.js?v=1.10.2, line 1: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead
JavaScript error: https://ondemand.questionmark.com/home/403160/sites/all/themes/questionmark/js/main.js?opnqsh, line 190: TypeError: textarea is null
1496492440306   Marionette  INFO    New connections will no longer be accepted
[Child 18404] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-esr52-w64-000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line 2143
Jun 03, 2017 1:20:41 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess destroy
SEVERE: Unable to kill process with PID 636

Comment: Using JUnit right? Version? Can you consider updating the entire stack trace in the question area? Thanks

Comment: can you try updating browser, driver and chk?

Comment: Yes am using Junit. I have also updated the browser driver but no luck.